# Set time in linux from c program

Tags: c, linux

I want to set/change time of my system from the c program. I searched a lot on the internet but have not found any satisfactory result. I had a llok on settimeofday but it requires seconds and microseconds passed since 1 January 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

but i want something like i can give explicitly Date, Year, Month, Hours, Minutes and seconds and UTC time shall be set.

Is there any c library function or any other mechanism available for that?

Comment: [A good reference of the standard date and time functions in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono) might be a good start.

Comment: You need [`mktime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) for the seconds part; you need to choose the sub-seconds carefully.  You need to be `root` to set the time.  Why not use the `date` command to do the job — it has a mode for that.

Comment: Note that setting the time may invalidate some software licences (like Oracle).  You may have to rebuild the OS because once it is detected as invalid, you can never set it back to a valid state.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the time in YYMMDDhhss format into a `struct time`. You can ignore the *day of week* and *day of year* fields. Put a negative value into `tm_isdst` to let the system decide whether DST is in effect on that day.
2. Call `mk_time` with a pointer to that `struct time` - it will fill the missing fields in the structure and return a `time_t` set to this date.
3. Use `settimeofday()` with that returned value in a `struct timeval` (The µs part to your liking). Use "NULL" for the timezone argument.

Note you need to have appropriate (root) privilege to set the system time, and also note that `settimeofday` has some special peculiarities on Linux, so it is thoroughly recommended to read the man pages

All of the above requires `time.h` included in you program, obviously.

Comment: mk_time should be mktime.